# JSON values parsed as undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

I am trying to parse a JSON in Javascript. The JSON is created as an ajax response:

```
$.ajax(url, {
  dataType: "text",
  success: function(rawData, status, xhr) {
    var data;
    try {
      data = $.parseJSON(rawData);
      var counter = data.counter;
      for(var i=1; i<=counter; i++){
        //since the number of 'testPath' elements in the JSON depend on the 'counter' variable, I am parsing it in this way
        //counter has the correct integer value and loops runs fine
        var currCounter = 'testPath'+i ;
        alert(data.currCounter); // everything alerts as undefined
      }
    } catch(err) {
      alert(err);
    }
  },
  error: function(xhr, status, err) {
    alert(err);
  }
});
```

But all values alert 'undefined' as value (except the 'counter' which gives correct value) The actual string as seen in firebug is as below:

```
{"testPath1":"ab/csd/sasa", "testPath2":"asa/fdfd/ghfgfg", "testPath3":"ssdsd/sdsd/sds", "counter":3}
```

Comment: why don't you use `dataType` as `JSON` and send response as `JSON` instead of `text` ??

Comment: Did you check your Javascript console for errors?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`alert(data[currCounter])` , this will work.

as `data.currCounter` looks for the key 'currCounter` in the object, not by the value of currCounter.

example:

http://jsfiddle.net/bJeWm/1/

```
var myObj = { 'name':'dhruv','age':28 };
var theKey = 'age';
alert(myObj.theKey);  // undefined
alert(myObj[theKey]); // 28
```

Comment: Thanks @DhruvPathak .. It just worked by using [] instead of "."

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
alert(data[currCounter]);
```

instead. You cannot access a property like you did....

Answer (score 2):

Need to use `[]` notation

```
data[currCounter]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try data[currCounter] because there is no value in data.currCount.